# JAX-WS and SWA Attachments

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, attachment

I'm building integration with SOAP API. Second side forced me to use SWA(SOAP with Attachment https://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments). I can't use MTOM. It is also not SWA-Ref(?). I successfully generated SOAP client and SOAP server with eclipse and Apache CXF. Simple messages works perfectly with basic auth and HTTPS.

I need to handle attachments. My SOAP client has to send files, my server has to recevie and save files.
Can JAX-WS handle MIME attachments?

Here is part of examplary SOAP message :

```xml
<ns3:attachments>
<ns0:attachment href="cid:5d1499240031a00380006998" contentId="cid:5d1499240031a00380006998" action="add" name="example.txt" type="text/plain" len="88" />
</ns3:attachments>
```

Here is WSDL pars defining attachemnts part:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="AttachmentType">
<xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="contentId" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="action" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="len" type="xs:int" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="charset" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="upload.by" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="upload.date" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="attachmentType" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="AttachmentsType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="attachment" type="AttachmentType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JAX-WS documentation](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/doc/user-guide/release-documentation.html#mtom-amp-swaref):

> MTOM and **swaRef** support was added in JAX-WS 2.0 RI FCS release. MTOM and swaref support is required by the JAX-WS 2.0 specification.

And according to [this](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/doc/user-guide/release-documentation.html#swaref):

> [WS-I Attachment Profile 1.0](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/AttachmentsProfile-1.0-2004-08-24.html) defines mechanism to reference MIME attachment parts using swaRef. In this mechanism the content of XML element of type `wsi:swaRef` is sent as MIME attachment and the element inside SOAP Body holds the reference to this attachment in the CID URI scheme as defined by [RFC 2111](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2111.html). JAXB 2.0 defines mapping of `wsi:swaRef` schema type to *javax.activation.DataHandler*. An application will construct the DataHandler with the data and the appropriate MIME type and JAX-WS will coordinate with JAXB and SAAJ to send it as attachment MIME part.

[Here](https://github.com/javaee/metro-jax-ws/tree/master/jaxws-ri/samples/src/main/samples/mime) you can find an example how you can accomplish this.